# Parameter [FETCHPARTIALLOB] is not valid for this configuration

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am new to Oracle Golden gate, there is a requirement to fetch all the LOB updated columns instead of only one delta from source to target replication.

I added TRANLOGOPTIONS FETCHPARTIALLOB in my extract. but getting the below error

Parameter [FETCHPARTIALLOB] is not valid for this configuration.

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happened because you have set up Extract process in classic capture mode. The FETCHPARTIALLOB option is valid only when the Extract process is set up in integrated capture mode.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Integrated capture is working as expected.